# AWS - RDS Service instance needs to start if it is in the stop state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am new to aws.In AWS - RDS services we are running 2 instances. Suddenly it went to stop mode whenever there is any updates or patchings happens from AWS-ends.

Can Anyone assist me is there any possible way to start it again when it goes to stop mode.

Actually This Database instance should be in start/running mode otherwise, our application won't work.

Answer (score 0):

An Amazon RDS instance will normally be running continuously.

You can [Stop an Amazon RDS DB Instance Temporarily - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_StopInstance.html#:~:targetText=Sign%20in%20to%20the%20AWS,For%20Actions%2C%20choose%20Stop.), but this requires that you specifically request that the database stop.

You could look through your **AWS CloudTrail** logs to see if another user requested that the database be stopped.

So, rather than worrying about how to start it in future, you should look into determining why it stopped. You can configure IAM permissions to remove the ability for users to stop the RDS database in future.

Comment: Hi john , Thanks for your response. But actually the rds instance stopped due to patching from AWS . So Just want to start it whenever it goes to shutdown state

Comment: I don't believe that patching causes an instance to have a state of "Stopped". What makes you think it was caused by patching? See also: [Maintaining a DB Instance - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.Maintenance.html)